# About the exact sequence $0\to $$Ш(E/\Bbb{Q})[\phi]\to Ш(E/\Bbb{Q})[2]\to Ш(E'/\Bbb{Q})[\hat{\phi}]$ in Silverman's book of elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, galois-cohomology

This question is about Silverman's book,$7$-th line from the bottom of $350$ page of 'The arithmetic of elliptic curves' ([http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~lowdimma/BSD/Silverman-Arithmetic_of_EC.pdf](http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/%7Elowdimma/BSD/Silverman-Arithmetic_of_EC.pdf)) .

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over number field $K$.
Let $\phi:E \to E'$ be an isogeny,
and $\hat{\phi}$ be its dual isogeny.

Then, the book reads there is exact sequence of Tate-Shafarevich group, namely,

**$0\to   $$Ш(E/\Bbb{Q})[\phi]\to Ш(E/\Bbb{Q})[2]\to Ш(E'/\Bbb{Q})[\hat{\phi}]$**

This exact sequence is obtained by taking long exact sequence Galois cohomology from short exact sequence
$　0\to{E(\Bbb{Q})[\phi]}\to E(\Bbb{Q})[2]\to E'(\Bbb{Q})[\hat{\phi}]$.

$0\to{E(\Bbb{Q})[\phi]}\to E(\Bbb{Q})[2]\to E'(\Bbb{Q})[\hat{\phi}]\to H^1(G_K,E(\Bbb{Q})[\phi])\to H^1(G_K,E(\Bbb{Q})[2])\to・・・$

Then we get $E'(\Bbb{Q})[\hat{\phi}]/\phi(E[2])\to H^1(G_K,E(\Bbb{Q})[\phi])\to H^1(G_K,E(\Bbb{Q})[2])\to・・・$

In the case $E'[\hat{\phi}]/\phi(E[2])=0$, this certainly induces exact sequence$0\to   $$Ш(E/\Bbb{Q})[\phi]\to Ш(E/\Bbb{Q})[2]\to Ш(E'/\Bbb{Q})[\hat{\phi}]$, but in Silverman' s book,$E[\hat{\phi}]/\phi(E[2])\cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$, thus we just get
$$Ш(E/\Bbb{Q})[\phi]\to Ш(E/\Bbb{Q})[2]\to Ш(E'/\Bbb{Q})[\hat{\phi}]$$ and the first map $Ш(E/\Bbb{Q})[\phi]\to Ш(E/\Bbb{Q})[2]$ is **not necesalliry injective**. But the book reads this is injective.

Where did I go wrong and how can I gain the titled exact sequence, $0\to   $$Ш(E/\Bbb{Q})[\phi]\to Ш(E/\Bbb{Q})[2]\to Ш(E'/\Bbb{Q})[\hat{\phi}]$ ?

Comment: There are still some errors. But the question you are asking us about deals with two subgroups of $Ш(E/\mathbb{Q})$, one clearly contained in the other. The sequence you want is the kernel-cokernel sequence of $\phi\circ\hat\phi$ induced on Ш.